# call to call a batch file from another batch file and pass control to former/

Tags: batch-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Several ways to call a windows batch file from another one or from prompt. Which one in which case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607856/several-ways-to-call-a-windows-batch-file-from-another-one-or-from-prompt-which)

The whole process is like this without using batch file:

1. Change directory to `c:\ris`.
2. Start a batch file `c:\python26\env\scripts\activate.bat`.
   This then starts some kind of python console,  prompt changes to `(env) c:\ris`.
3. Here I run command `paster serve --reload development.ini`.

I have done step 1 and 2 but cannot co step 3. When I run my batch file (`mapfishstart.bat`) I can open new console of `activate.bat` but cannot automatically pass the command to `activate.bat` (I have to type it in and want it to be automatic). I would not prefer any changes to `activate.bat` file.

Can anyone help to automate 3rd process?

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your question correctly and you want to automatically run a command within console, then `echo paster serve --reload development.ini | c:\python26\env\scripts\activate.bat` *may* work, dependant on whether any commands before the one which starts python console consumes stdin or not.