# Can I run multiple CakePHP console commands from a batch file?

Tags: cakephp, batch-file, console

I have a batch file that contains:

```
cake RunPayroll 
cake RunInvoices
cake Run[etc.]
```

But when I run it, only the first command completes, then the batch file stops. What's the secret to running multiple console commands from a single batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `call`:

```
call cake RunPayroll 
call cake RunInvoices
```

See [Several ways to call a windows batch file from another one or from prompt. Which one in which case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607856/several-ways-to-call-a-windows-batch-file-from-another-one-or-from-prompt-which)