# Running .jar file from .bat file and then doing executing other commands

Tags: batch-file, jar, command-prompt

I am performing one task where I have to run one .jar file using batch file which is called by another batch file. After execution I need to delete some junk files. Code to delete files is written in the same calling batch file.

Now issue is that once .jar file starts executing , command window closes and then control never comes back to batch file execution hence my delete code never works.

Is there any way to resolve this issue.

Thanks
Amit

Below is the code I am using.

```
@Echo off

echo "your file is getting processed...."

md %userprofile%\temp

echo %userprofile%\temp


'"C:\Program Files\winzip\Winzip64.exe" -min -e -o C:\mysoft\Benchmarks\Windows7.zip %userprofile%\temp

C:
cd %userprofile%\temp\Windows7
echo going to execute file...

soft-CAT.bat -a -s -n -csv -b benchmarks\soft_Microsoft_Windows_7_Benchmark_v2.1.0-xccdf.xml -p "Level 1 + BitLocker" -r c:\

set folder="C:\test\junk"
cd /d %folder%
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)

ECHO "Successfully Evaluated"

Exit
```

Called batch file

```
@ECHO OFF
::
:: Wrapper for invoking soft-CAT
::

SET DEBUG=0

SET JAVA=java

::
:: Detect if Java is in the path
::

%JAVA% 2> NUL > NUL

IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==9009 IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==3 GOTO RUNSOFTCAT

::
:: If Java is not in the PATH, try finding it at JAVA_HOME\bin
::

SET JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe

%JAVA% 2> NUL > NUL

IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==9009 IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==3 GOTO RUNSOFTCAT

::
:: See if x86 JRE5 is in the default location
::

SET JAVA=C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre5\bin\java.exe

%JAVA% 2> NUL > NUL

IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==9009 IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==3 GOTO RUNSOFTCAT

::
:: See if x86 JRE6 is in the default location
::

SET JAVA=C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe

%JAVA% 2> NUL > NUL

IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==9009 IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==3 GOTO RUNSOFTCAT

::
:: See if x86 JRE7 is in the default location
::

SET JAVA=C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe

%JAVA% 2> NUL > NUL

IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==9009 IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==3 GOTO RUNSOFTCAT

::
:: See if x86 JRE8 is in the default location
::

SET JAVA=C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre8\bin\java.exe

%JAVA% 2> NUL > NUL

IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==9009 IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==3 GOTO RUNSOFTCAT

::
:: See if JRE6 is in the default location
::

SET JAVA=C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe

%JAVA% 2> NUL > NUL

IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==9009 IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==3 GOTO RUNSOFTCAT

::
:: See if JRE7 is in the default location
::

SET JAVA=C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe

%JAVA% 2> NUL > NUL

IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==9009 IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==3 GOTO RUNSOFTCAT

::
:: See if JRE8 is in the default location
::

SET JAVA=C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jre8\bin\java.exe

%JAVA% 2> NUL > NUL

IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==9009 IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==3 GOTO RUNSOFTCAT

IF %ERRORLEVEL%==9009 GOTO NOJAVAERROR
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==3 GOTO NOJAVAERROR

::
:: Invoke SOFT-CAT with a 768MB heap
::

:RUNSOFTCAT

IF %DEBUG%==1 (
    ECHO Found Java at %JAVA%
    %JAVA% -Xmx768M -jar SOFTCAT.jar %* --verbose
) ELSE (
    %JAVA% -Xmx768M -jar SOFTCAT.jar %*
)
echo "I am in main file, execution is done...."
GOTO EXIT

:NOJAVAERROR

ECHO The Java runtime was not found in PATH, default install locations, or JAVA_HOME.  Please ensure Java is installed.
PAUSE

:EXIT
```

Comment: This is calling file..

Answer (score 0):

Try putting CALL in front of the batch file name like this:

```
call soft-CAT.bat -a -s -n -csv -b benchmarks\soft_Microsoft_Windows_7_Benchmark_v2.1.0-xccdf.xml -p "Level 1 + BitLocker" -r c:\
```

Very good information the different ways to call a batch file from another batch file here: [Several ways to call a windows batch file from another one or from prompt. Which one in which case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607856/several-ways-to-call-a-windows-batch-file-from-another-one-or-from-prompt-which)

Answer (score 0):

If you start a batch file from a batch file you *replace* the latter with the first one. If you want a batch file to run as a subroutine you need to *call* it:

```
REM this is FIRST.BAT
echo Now I call the second one
CALL SECOND.BAT
echo SECOND.BAT has finished!

REM this is SECOND.BAT
echo Doing things ...
```