# Execute .bat file from within paver task

Tags: python, batch-file, paver

How can i execute a batch file in a task defined with the python module **paver**? Do i have to distinguish on what operating system (unix/windows) the paver task will be executed?

E.g. the following task defined in *pavement.py* in the projects root directory does execute all unit tests (defined with python standard library module *unittest*) defined in the project

```
from paver.tasks import task
from paver.easy import sh

@task
def unit_tests():
"""
Run all unit tests.
"""
    sh('python -m unittest')
```

if one does execute

```
paver unit_tests
```

from the command line in the projects root directory.

However i am not able to execute a batchfile file on a windows operating system (located in the project root directory) with

```
sh('batchfile.bat')
```

I am also not able to execute a batch file in a sub-directory *venv/Scripts* of the projects root directory using the *cwd* argument of *sh()* [[paver source code](https://github.com/paver/paver/blob/master/paver/shell.py)] with one of the following alternatives

```
# no call does execute the batch file (*cwd* alternatives)
sh('batchfile.bat', cwd='venv/Scripts')
sh('cmd /c batchfile.bat', cwd='venv/Scripts')

# no call does execute the batch file (*sh()* "sequential command" syntax alternatives)
sh('cd venv/Scripts; deactivate.bat')
sh('cd venv/Scripts; cmd /c deactivate.bat')

# this sequence does also not execute the batch file (absolute path alternative)
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'venv\Scripts')
sh('deactivate.bat', cwd=path)
```

EDIT:

I created a batch file  *hello_world.bat* not related with "virtualenv processing" in the root directory and the sub directory venv/Scripts/:

```
@echo off
echo hello world
pause
```

Calling

```
paver root_dir_call
```

or

```
paver sub_dir_call
```

in the project root directory on **windows** with the added paver tasks in *pavement.py* do execute the batch file, [do execute the batch file with side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607856/several-ways-to-call-a-windows-batch-file-from-another-one-or-from-prompt-which) or do not execute the batch file dependent on the specific uncommented *sh()* command:

```
@task
def root_dir_call():
    # use one of these two calls!
    sh('hello_world.bat') # PASS
    #sh('hello_world') # PASS

    # do not use other calls like these two because they have side effects or do not execute the batch file at all
    #sh('call hello_world.bat') # PASS (execution with side effects)
    #sh('cmd /c hello_world.bat') # PASS (execution with side effects)
    #sh('start hello_world.bat') # PASS (execution with side effects)
    #sh('cmd hello_world.bat') # FAIL (no execution, output of cmd!?)
```

and

```
@task
def sub_dir_call():
    # use one of these calls!
    sh('hello_world.bat', cwd='venv/Scripts/') # PASS
    #sh('hello_world', cwd='venv/Scripts') # PASS
    #sh('hello_world', cwd='venv\Scripts') # PASS

    # following calls do not execute the batch file
    #sh('cd venv/Scripts; hello_world.bat') # FAIL
    #sh('cd venv/Scripts/; hello_world.bat') # FAIL
    #sh('cd venv\Scripts\; hello_world.bat') # FAIL
    #sh('cd venv/Scripts; cmd /c hello_world.bat') # FAIL
```

Comment: My problem is related to the virtualenv context: I am not able to execute the batchfile deactivate.bat as it does deactivate the virtualenv in which the paver module is installed and in which the paver command is executed. I am able to execute another batch file which is not related to the virtualenv. I will edit the question accoring to its heading.

Comment: It is possible to [call .bat files from linux using wine](http://www.linux.org/threads/running-windows-batch-files-on-linux.7610/)

Comment: Paver has a virtualenv support which allows to use the decorator @virtualenv(dir="venv") to define a virtual environment in which the task shall be executed. This requires that the module **paver** is installed in the python virtualenv which is used to call the paver commands of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the current release of paver has a [bug related to the virtualenv support on windows systems see this issue](https://github.com/paver/paver/issues/155).